# Adding and removing variable on href element?

Tags: jquery

I have 2 boxes with `data-attributes` for 2 different pages. When you click `A` the `href` should change from `index.html` to `index.html/a`, and if you click `B` it should remove `/a` and add `/b`.

I've been able to change the variable, but not when you click another box. So I get `index.html/a/b`. I guess it should be toggle between the two boxes.

**HTML**

```
<div class="box" data-id="a"></div>

<div class="box" data-id="b"></div>

<a class="link" href="index.html>Click Me</a>
```

**JS**

```
$('.box').on('click', function() {

   var box_id = $(this).data('id');

   if($(this).data('id') === box_id) {
       $('.link').attr('href', function() {
           return.href + '?' + box_id;
       }); 
   }
});
```

Comment: `$(this).data('id') === box_id` will always return true, also, maybe a typo here? `return.href`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will grab the current href from the link and remove either `/a` or `/b` and append the ID of the box you clicked.

(I added styles to the boxes to make them visible in the snippet)

```js
var link = $('a');

$('.box').on('click', function () {
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  var newHref = link.attr('href').replace(/\/(a|b)/, '') + '/' + id;
  link.attr('href', newHref);
  $('#result').text(newHref);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" data-id="a" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:red"></div>

<div class="box" data-id="b" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:blue"></div>

<a class="link" href="index.html">Click Me</a>
                      
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Exactly what I was looking for.